# How to animate color of a Container by spreading it from the middle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-animation

In my Flutter App, I have used an `AnimatedContainer` for my widget. I want that whenever the state of my color changes, It should start spreading from the middle and continue spreading on both sides till the end.

Here is What I have written:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: widget.controller._getLoading,
          builder: (context, _ControllerState controllerState, child) {
            return AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              height: widget.height ?? 56,
              margin: widget.margin,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _getColor(controllerState),
                borderRadius: widget.borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: _getCenterWidget(controllerState),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a box that can change color, and you want the new color to spread from the center of the box to its edges whenever it changes. To do this, you can use two things:

- **Tween animations:** These are like instructions that tell the color how to change gradually from one to another. So, instead of the color
  instantly changing, it smoothly transitions from the old color to the
  new one.
- **CustomPainter:** This is like an artist who can paint anything you want. In this case, we'll use it to draw the box and control how the
  color spreads from the center to the edges.

So, when you want to change the color of the box:

1. First, you want to use `Tween` animations to smoothly transition from
   the old color to the new one.
2. After that, you use `CustomPainter` to draw the box, making sure the
   color spreads from the middle to the edges.

Now we try to use those two things,

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: widget.controller._getLoading,
  builder: (context, _ControllerState controllerState, child) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      height: widget.height ?? 56,
      margin: widget.margin,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _getColor(controllerState),
        borderRadius: widget.borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: _getCenterWidget(controllerState),
      ),
      foregroundDecoration: controllerState == _ControllerState.loading
          ? BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [
                  _getColor(controllerState).withOpacity(0),
                  _getColor(controllerState),
                  _getColor(controllerState),
                  _getColor(controllerState).withOpacity(0),
                ],
                stops: [0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0],
              ),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
);
```

- **Gradient:** Think of it like a blend of colors that smoothly change from one to another. In this case, it starts from being invisible,
  then gradually becomes the desired color in the middle of the
  container (at 40% of its width), and then goes back to being
  invisible towards the edges.
- **Stops values and colors:** These are just settings that control how the gradient looks. By adjusting them, you can make the colors blend
  in the way you want. For example, you can make the middle part
  brighter or darker, or change how fast it fades out towards the
  edges.
- **Animating the color change:** When the color changes, the gradient doesn't just snap to the new color. Instead, it smoothly transitions
  from the old color to the new one, creating a cool spreading effect
  from the middle to the edges of the container.